# Zend_Input_Filter - how to add several validators to 1 data field

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework

What is the right way to assign a few validators to the same data field when using Zend_Input_Filter.

E.g. my validators array is this and I need to validations on Field2:

```
$validators = array(
            'Field1' => array(
                'NotEmpty',
                'messages' => 'Field1 must be filled'
                ),
            'Feild2' => array(
                'NotEmpty',
                'messages' => 'Field2 must be selected'
                ),
            'Field2' => array(
                'Digits',
                'messages' => 'Field2 must be numeric'
                ),
        );
```

Then I call

```
$input = new Zend_Filter_Input(null, $validators, $data);
```

But I guess I can't use array key 'Field2' twise. 
Then how to I bind to validators to just 1 field?

P.S. Well, I know the hard way is to stuff all field validators into one class,
but I hope there is and easy ZF way, the configuration way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$validators = array(
            'Field1' => array(
                'NotEmpty', 'Digits', new Zend_Validate_Blahblah(),
                'messages' => array('Field1 must be filled', 
                                    'Field1 must be numeric', 
                                    'Field1 must be a blahblah')
                ),
            ...
        );
```

Give this a read:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html